# PHP POST tmpfile()

Tags: php, html, web-development-server

I am trying to create live editing of a server file on an other server. I managed to download and save it as tmpfile(). After editing the file I want to save the changes. my HTML code looks like this:

```
<body>


<form method='post'>

<textarea name='text' class='textfield' id='textf'>$text</textarea>

<input type='submit'>
<input type='hidden' name='valuea' value='$server'>
<input type='hidden' name='valueb' value='$user'>
<input type='hidden' name='valuec' value='$safelocation'>
<input type='file' name='temp' value='$tempfile'>
</form>
</body>
```

I am not able to send the `$tempfile` again to my php code. I tried to cast the POST value as resource but that will not be a/the same temp file. `$file = (resource)($_POST['temp']);`
How could I manage to send the same file I editied to the same php script and use it again?

Comment: You can't provide an initial value to a `file` input, the user has to select the file by hand.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you intend by this. A `file` input is for uploading a file from the client machine, it has nothing to do with server files.

Comment: Resources are only temporary values on the server, they can't be sent from one script execution to another.